# Difference between CRC errors and FCS errors?

Tags: switch, ethernet

Is there an actual difference between a CRC error and a FCS error?

After reading a lot, they seem like the same thing, but most switches and readings refer to them as separate entities.

Is there an overlap of these counters on a switch interface?

Comment: Usually the same thing, but if you post the context of where you read this, we could say for sure.

Comment: This is an easy reference I found, [link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/12027-53.html). The two are mentioned separately.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

It was my understanding that CRC is the algorithm that FCS uses to do its check. Meaning that the Frame Relay, PPP and other protocols have the CRC to be used as the algorithm to calculate the FCS as defined in their standard. Other protocols could include a FCS but use a different algorithm besides CRC.